# How do i reduce the width of a full-width Wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Thanks to anyone who responds in advance. My website at http://mediaroomhub.com is a full-width website theme. Please how do i reduce the width so that the background picture can show like I have it in the picture? I am not really good at CSS. I tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
.sec-marg-out, .sec-marg-out2, .sec-marg-out4 {
width: 80%;
```

}

[I want it like this please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjrpq.png)

Comment: If it has a wrapper, apply a max-width: 90% to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a specific rule to your `#site`:

```
#site {
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

This overrules the current absolute position of your site (in full screen) and applies a 90% width to it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Roberrrt. I tried it but its not working. Or is there a specific way to do it? I am so new to this. I am very sorry if I am overlooking the obvious. Thank you.

Comment: Woops, my bad, I copy pasted the wrong snippet, the selector should obviously point to #site, i've updated my answer.

Comment: Oh my God, you are the best Roberrrt. I just tested it on localhost and it works perfectly. You just made my day. Thanks buddy. :) :D